# How to setup OpenVPN?

Tags: openvpn

How do I setup openVPN on Win7? Most of the tutorials online are simple copy-paste into the config folder.
is there a better way to do it that explains what to do and more importantly`why to do it`

Comment: Better way? What have you tried so far? Are you telling me [the instructions on the site](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#install) are of no use? As for why, what specifically about the instructions is difficult to understand? Also, what precisely are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.giganews.com/vyprvpn/setup/windows-7/openvpn.html) link. This will guide you to install OpenVPN